# Adding methods to two events at the same time

Tags: c#, events, event-handling, click, keypress

I making a custom button, and I need to add a PreviewKeyDown event, whenever i add a Click event. What i got so far is:

```
public new event EventHandler Click { 
    add { 
        base.Click += value; 
        foreach (Control i in Controls) { 
            i.Click += value; 
        } 
    } 
    remove { 
        base.Click -= value; 
        foreach (Control i in Controls) { 
            i.Click -= value; 
        } 
    } 
}
```

this adds the click event to everything, but i need to add one method to a click event AND a PreviewKeyDown event at the same time in winforms. its for a custom button, so it can perform a method when someone hits enter

if something is unclear just comment and ill clarify

Comment: coudln't you just say `base.PreviewKeyDown = value` as well in `add` section?

Comment: that didnt work, but a variation of it did... i did base.PreviewKeyDown += new PreviewKeyDownEventHandler(value); Thanks

Comment: This works. In the handler you will have to cast the `EventArgs e` to either `MouseEventArgs` or `PreviewKeyDownEventArgs` in order to do something useful with them.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes just using EventArgs e worked fine, thanks though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Completed code:

```
public new event EventHandler Click {
add {
base.Click += value;
base.PreviewKeyDown += new PreviewKeyDownEventHandler(value);
foreach (Control i in Controls) {
i.Click += value;
i.PreviewKeyDown += new PreviewKeyDownEventHandler(value);
}
}
remove {
//same code with -= instead of +=, but the previewkeydown event is excluded because i couldnt find a way to remove it.
}
}
```